# scala column object to single-column dataframe

Tags: scala, dataframe, apache-spark, types, casting

I have a dataframe like this:

```scala
      val df = Seq(
      ("a", Seq(2.0)),
      ("a", Seq(1.0)),
      ("a", Seq(0.5)),
      ("b", Seq(24.0)),
      ("b", Seq(12.5)),
      ("b", Seq(6.4)),
      ("b", Seq(3.2)),
      ("c", Seq(104.0)),
      ("c", Seq(107.4))
    ).toDF("key", "value")
```

I need to use an algorithm that takes in input a DataFrame object on distinct groups. 
To make this clearer, assume that I have to use StandardScaler scaling by groups.

In pandas I would do something like this (many type changes in the process):

```py
from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler
       df.groupby(key) \
       .value \
       .transform(lambda x: StandardScaler \
       .fit_transform(x \
       .values \
       .reshape(-1,1)) \
       .reshape(-1))
```

I need to do this in scala because the algorithm I need to use is not the Scaler but another thing built in scala.

So far I've tried to do something like this:

```scala
import org.apache.spark.ml.feature.StandardScaler
def f(X : org.apache.spark.sql.Column) : org.apache.spark.sql.Column = {  
      val scaler = new StandardScaler()
        .setInputCol("value")
        .setOutputCol("scaled")

      val output = scaler.fit(X)("scaled")

      (output)

    }

    df.withColumn("scaled_values", f(col("features")).over(Window.partitionBy("key")))
```

but of course it gives me an error:

> command-144174313464261:21: error: type mismatch;
>   found   : org.apache.spark.sql.Column
>   required: org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset[_]
>    val output = scaler.fit(X)("scaled")

So I'm trying to transform a single Column object into a DataFrame object, without success. How do I do it?

If it's not possible, is there any workaround to solve this?

**UPDATE 1**

It seems I made some mistakes in the code, I tried to fix it (I think I did right):

```scala
      val df = Seq(
      ("a", 2.0),
      ("a", 1.0),
      ("a", 0.5),
      ("b", 24.0),
      ("b", 12.5),
      ("b", 6.4),
      ("b", 3.2),
      ("c", 104.0),
      ("c", 107.4)
    ).toDF("key", "value")


    def f(X : org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame) : org.apache.spark.sql.Column = {  
         val assembler = new VectorAssembler()
        .setInputCols(Array("value"))
        .setOutputCol("feature")
          val scaler = new StandardScaler()
        .setInputCol("feature")
        .setOutputCol("scaled")
         val pipeline = new Pipeline()
        .setStages(Array(assembler, scaler))
         val output = pipeline.fit(X).transform(X)("scaled")

      (output)
    }  

    someDF.withColumn("scaled_values", f(someDF).over(Window.partitionBy("key")))
```

I still get an error:

> org.apache.spark.sql.AnalysisException: Expression 'scaled#1294' not
>   supported within a window function.;;

I am not sure about the reason for this error, I tried aliasing the column but it doesn't seem to work.

Answer (score 2):

> So I'm trying to transform a single Column object into a DataFrame object, without success. How do I do it?

You can't, a `column` just references a `column` of a DataFrame, it does not contain any data, it's not a data structure like a dataframe.

Your `f` function will also not work like this. If you want to create a custom function to be used with `Window`, then you need an UDAF (User-Defined-Aggregation-Function), which is pretty hard...

In your case, I would to a groupBy `key`, collect_list of your values, then apply an UDF to do the scaling. Note that this only works of the data per key is not too large (larger than what fits into 1 executor), otherwise you need UDAF

Here an example:

```
// example scala method, scale to 0-1
def myScaler(data:Seq[Double]) = {
  val mi = data.min
  val ma = data.max
  data.map(x => (x-mi)/(ma-mi))
}

val udf_myScaler = udf(myScaler _)

df
  .groupBy($"key")
  .agg(
    collect_list($"value").as("values")
  )
  .select($"key",explode(arrays_zip($"values",udf_myScaler($"values"))))
  .select($"key",$"col.values",$"col.1".as("values_scaled"))
  .show()
```

gives:

```
+---+------+-------------------+
|key|values|      values_scaled|
+---+------+-------------------+
|  c| 104.0|                0.0|
|  c| 107.4|                1.0|
|  b|  24.0|                1.0|
|  b|  12.5|0.44711538461538464|
|  b|   6.4|0.15384615384615385|
|  b|   3.2|                0.0|
|  a|   2.0|                1.0|
|  a|   1.0| 0.3333333333333333|
|  a|   0.5|                0.0|
+---+------+-------------------+
```

Comment: Thank you for the reply! I tried your code, and I get this error: `org.apache.spark.SparkException: Task not serializable`. I also have this problem: I am try to run an anomaly detection algorithm (IsolationForest) on the various groups, so it's quite difficult for me to rewrite all the code of the algorithm as a function that ingests a list of values. It seems to me that, unless I do that, I won't be able to complete this task. Furthermore, If I have to put everything in one single executor, do not I lose the cool side of the spark parallelism?